# GHC performance implications of parametric types

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'll motivate the general question with a more specific one:

In GHC Haskell, should a `Cofree [] a` have the same performance as a `containers`-style `Data.Tree a`? Or does the additional polymorphism result in some kind of runtime cost?

Generally speaking, is there additional runtime cost associated with increasing "arity" of a type's kind?

Comment: Types are not represented at runtime. Is this specifically about `Cofree` vs specific implementations? Because `Cofree` is well-known to be non-performant.

Comment: @AJFarmar do you have any links that explain why `Cofree` has poor performance, then?

Comment: Somewhat: https://markkarpov.com/post/free-monad-considered-harmful.html

Answer (score 1):

I think a more classic concrete example would be something like vectors or arrays. The [vector package](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.17/package/vector-0.12.0.1) exports both "boxed" and "unboxed" vectors. While boxed vectors can contain any Haskell type (including functions), unboxed vectors requires its elements to be an instance of the `Unbox` type class. Although this implies a more efficient packed memory representation without pointer indirections, you can't define a `Functor` instance for unboxed vectors anymore, so it comes with a loss of generality.

If you made use of

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Vector a -> Vector b
```

in a function of type

```
f :: Functor f => f SomeType -> f SomeOtherType
```

a "Dictionary", that is, a record with the corresponding `fmap` implementation will be passed at run-time as an additional implicit argument. You can actually see this by looking at the "Core" output produced by GHC, using the [`-ddump-simpl`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/debugging.html#dumping-out-compiler-intermediate-structures) flag. Specifically, the arity of `f` above would be two instead of one.

In some cases, GHC can optimize this overhead away by creating specialized versions of your functions. You can help out via using [SPECIALIZE/INLINABLE/...](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pragmas) pragmas, using explicit export lists, maybe adding some strictness, and a few other tweaks which are also described [in the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/sooner.html#faster-producing-a-program-that-runs-quicker).

Regarding the overhead of using parametrically polymorphic types, it of course depends. My personal worst case was a factor 100 in an inner numeric loop (which was resolved by adding one SPECIALIZE pragma), so it *can* indeed bite you. Luckily, using the profiling tools and remembering that dictionaries influence a function's arity, tracking these issues down becomes very systematic.